# CodeWorkout's "hidden tests" are telling me my code didn't return the right number, despite passing every test

Tags: java, arrays, average

I have some code here made to create the average of any array greater than 3 elements. Basically, I need to remove the largest and smallest elements and then get the average of everything in-between.
My code is most likely terrible, but it passed all the tests on [CodeWorkout](https://codeworkout.cs.vt.edu) except for the "hidden tests".

So essentially my issue is that I have no idea why it would print wrong. My guess is that I didn't code it to anticipate arrays lower than 2 elements, or I just didn't do it the right way. I'm not allowed to import anything, and I'm only allowed to write code for this specific method.

```
public int centeredAverage(int[] nums){ 
int cout = 0;
int smallest = nums[0];
int largest = 0;
int average = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
    if(nums[i] < smallest){
        smallest = nums[i];
    }
    if(nums[i] > largest){
        largest = nums[i];
    }
    average += nums[i];
}
average = average - smallest - largest;
return average / (nums.length - 2);}
```

Comment: JavaScript and Java are not related

Comment: You probably should not assume that the largest is zero.

Comment: You're not doing any edge case / sanity checks. I can't tell if you did that before this method was invoked, or if they promise not to send that as input, but this is easily broken by sending empty array, array less than 3 elements (if 2, divide by zero exception), negative numbers...

Comment: @Nikki9696 Yeah, that makes sense. I'll check to see if I can do casing to check for negatives, as that's the only one I can assume would be in the tests.

Comment: `average = average - smallest - largest;` What if the `smallest` value appears twice in the array?  You are not compensating for it appearing twice, unless you only need to take into account each largest or smallest a single time.

Comment: @Nexevis Don't worry, it wants me to ignore copies, so I can simply take one of the copies of the largest/smallest and it'll work out. It has a test where nums = {7,7,7} and it expects 7, but if I remove copies I'll be dividing by zero anyways.

Answer (score 1):

What is the exact requirement?

```
   Largest      Smallest
      |            |
2, 4, 16, 5, 7, 4, 1, 8, 1
          |  |  |
      Everything Between (1)

2, 4, 16, 5, 7, 4, 1, 8, 1
|  |      |  |  |     |
Everything Between (2)
```

For negative numbers, or in general:

```
int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

`Arrays.sort(int[] numbers)` might be helpful.

Having more than one smallest or largest might alter the average; your nums.length - 2.

You are doing integer division, 13 / 5 = 2. With rounding you would need: (I have renamed `average` to `sum`.

```
sum = sum - smallest - largest;
int n = nums.length - 2;
return n <= 2 ? 0 : (sum + n/2) / n;
```

Comment: Pardon me for not clarifying; "everything between" is essentially any number higher than 'smallest' and lower than 'largest'. I'll see if using max_value and min_value works better.

Comment: Definitely worked and I got full points for it. If I had any rep I would've upvoted you so fast.

Comment: My _"Everything Between (2)"_  leaves out 3 extremes: 16, 1, and 1.